# How to test jspdf autotable empty cells?

Tags: jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to make a PDF version of crossword puzzles. Is there a way to test cells content ( cells with empty strings or cells with just nothing ) in order to paint them black?

Comment: Have you tried specifying an empty string?

Comment: It's a game with two grids, one containing empty strings, the other empty cells. But I can easily use empty strings in the two grids.

Comment: Whats the difference between empty cells and cells with empty strings?

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.nvconsult.be/grille_29.pdf 
In the upper table (divided in two columns), each number figures the letter of a word. When the word is shorter than the others, there is no data for filling the trailing cells. 
But the lower table is filled with a text where the spaces are replaced by empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `createdCell` hook to dynamically change styles of cells depending on there content.

Comment: It works! Testing  ( typeof cell.raw === 'undefined' ) for my upper grid.